# String format change from frontend

Tags: c#, sql, database, string

Here i have one string value `0515` and i want to display `1505` from frontend(C#).

Anyone have any idea ?

```
String Str1 = ds.table[0].rows[a][5];
```

From `Str1` im getting `0515` but i want to display as `1505`.

Comment: Is there any logic to this change? What have you tried? Where are you trying to display this?

Comment: so, you want to display last two characters at first place?

Comment: yes Usman. I need to display that in label

Comment: Yes ryadavilli. My client like to display like that

Comment: That (rearranging arbitrary characters) simply isn't something that string.Format offers

Answer (score 1):

```
string temp = ds.table[0].rows[a][5];
string Str1 = temp.Substring(2) + temp.Substring(0, 2);
```

Comment: +1 With the given requirements, this is perfect. What the hell the point is, is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to d this without using Concatenation string is as follow

```
string Str1 = string.Format("{0}{1}", s1.Substring(2), s1.Substring(0, 2));
```